# How do I see if a button with an imageIcon loaded has been pressed in java?

Tags: java, button, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a program where I have a settings button. This button has an image icon which shows an image. Any tips on how I can preform an action when it is pressed. Here is that code

```
JButton imageButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("/Users/Sam/Programming/Files/gears.png"));
```

It works fine. But when I want to use

```
else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals(imageButton)){//doStuff}
```

it doesnt work. My action preformed method works, here it is

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{}
```

Comment: getActionCommand() returns a String not an Object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand()

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionListerner is not responding because getActionCommand() should return a String. In this case it should be the name of the JButton.

```
 else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals(imageButton.getText())){//doStuff}
```

Changing it to imageButton.getText() should solve the problem.

If you are not sure, just manually set the ActionCommand through setActionCommand() and use the same String to verify getActionCommand in the .equals() method.